# How to restart Explorer as a pre-build event in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, explorer, prebuild

I'd like to restart Explorer when building my DLL in Visual Studio.  I've tried adding `taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe` and `start explorer` as pre-build events in the project configuration.  When I then build my project, Explorer will in fact be terminated, but it will not be successfully restarted. The taskbar will remain missing. Only after starting explorer from a command prompt will it return. I've also tried executing a `call` to those commands in a `.bat` file, but I get the same problem (although the .bat file works properly when executed on its own, outside Visual Studio). I've also tried putting the relaunch part in a post-build event, but no dice. Is there any trick to getting Explorer to relaunch successfully in a pre-build event?  Thanks for any input.

Comment: `Start` is an internal command in `cmd.exe`, so, as you've already stated that it works from the Command Prompt, _(`cmd.exe`)_, does `Cmd /C Start Explorer` not work? Or just `Explorer` on its own?

Comment: No, unless I'm doing something wrong, those don't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can restart Explorer by putting the following commands into a Batch file:

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
exit
```

(The `/f` switch will *f*orce the termination of Explorer.)

Then, you can execute that Batch file as a pre-build step (Build Events → Pre-Build Event → Command Line).

If this is a necessary part of your build process, I would recommend adding this Batch file to your solution directory, committing it to your version-control system, and using a relative path in your solution properties.